# How to detect when facebook's FB.init is complete

Tags: javascript, facebook

The old JS SDK had a function called FB.ensureInit. The new SDK does not seem to have such function... how can I ensure that I do not make api calls until it is fully initiated?

I include this in the top of every page:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId  : '<?php echo $conf['fb']['appid']; ?>',
      status : true, // check login status
      cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml  : true  // parse XFBML
    });
    FB.Canvas.setAutoResize();
  };

  (function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script');
    e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    e.async = true;
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
  }());
</script>
```

Comment: See this link for my solution to this problem.
http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/12399428/facebook-javascript-sdk-not-firing-internet-explorer/14484209#14484209

Answer (score 141, accepted):

**Update on Jan 04, 2012**

It seems like you can't just call FB-dependent methods (for example `FB.getAuthResponse()`) right after `FB.init()` like before, as `FB.init()` seems to be asynchronous now. Wrapping your code into `FB.getLoginStatus()` response seems to do the trick of detecting when API is fully ready:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        //...
    });

    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response){
        runFbInitCriticalCode(); 
    });

};
```

or if using `fbEnsureInit()` implementation from below:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        //...
    });

    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response){
        fbApiInit = true;
    });

};
```

---

**Original Post:**

If you want to just run some script when FB is initialized you can put some callback function inside `fbAsyncInit`:

```
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId  : '<?php echo $conf['fb']['appid']; ?>',
      status : true, // check login status
      cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml  : true  // parse XFBML
    });
    FB.Canvas.setAutoResize();

    runFbInitCriticalCode(); //function that contains FB init critical code
  };
```

If you want exact replacement of FB.ensureInit then you would have to write something on your own as there is no official replacement (big mistake imo). Here is what I use:

```
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId  : '<?php echo $conf['fb']['appid']; ?>',
      status : true, // check login status
      cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml  : true  // parse XFBML
    });
    FB.Canvas.setAutoResize();

    fbApiInit = true; //init flag
  };

  function fbEnsureInit(callback) {
        if(!window.fbApiInit) {
            setTimeout(function() {fbEnsureInit(callback);}, 50);
        } else {
            if(callback) {
                callback();
            }
        }
    }
```

Usage:

```
fbEnsureInit(function() {
    console.log("this will be run once FB is initialized");
});
```

Comment: I'm not able to run a Facebook API request immediately after FB.init is called -- perhaps because the method I'm using is 'fql.query'?  Either way, I have to set a lengthy timeout on the fbApiInit flag.

Comment: Thanks for the update - I was having the same problem and your updated solution worked perfectly!

Comment: @beanland, fql.query api calls require that the user has logged in. Are you sure that you are running the query after getting a `response` back from `FB.getLoginStatus(function(response){}`? -- note the difference the "updated answer" vs. the "original answer" above.

Comment: @serg thank you for the example.  I had to put a delay on my function inside `fbAsyncInit` for it to be called after load `window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
 FB.init({
  appId      : '*************',
  channelUrl : 'http://www.mydomain.com',
  status     : true, // check login status
  cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
  oauth      : true, // enable OAuth 2.0
  xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
 });
 setTimeout(function() {
   myfunction(function (callback) {}, '', '', '' );
 }, 1200); 
};`

Comment: if this isn't working for you - then you probably made a stupid mistake with mismatched `});` - so check again :-)

Comment: @anyone who knows>>> Where to put the access token?

Answer (score 39):

Actually Facebook has already provided a mechanism to subscribe to authentication events.

In your case you are using "**status: true**" which means that FB object will request Facebook for user's login status.

```
FB.init({
    appId  : '<?php echo $conf['fb']['appid']; ?>',
    status : true, // check login status
    cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
    xfbml  : true  // parse XFBML
});
```

By calling "FB.getLoginStatus()" you are running the same request *again*.

Instead you could use [FB.Event.subscribe](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/) to subscribe to **auth.statusChange** or **auth.authResponseChange** event **BEFORE** you call FB.init

```
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', function(response) {
    if(response.status == 'connected') {
        runFbInitCriticalCode();
    }
});

FB.init({
    appId  : '<?php echo $conf['fb']['appid']; ?>',
    status : true, // check login status
    cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
    xfbml  : true  // parse XFBML
});
```

Most likely, when using "**status: false**" you can run any code right after FB.init, because there will be no asynchronous calls.

Comment: NOTE : With this method the only caveat is that, if you are not logged in, the event will not be triggered. Just make your default UI state as if not authenticated, and it works perfectly.  You can then check for connected or not_authorized inside of the event handler.

Comment: Also, for front-end apps, to maintain user login status between refreshes, set `cookie` to `true` in the init param object.

Answer (score 12):

Here is a solution in case you use [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) and Facebook Asynchronous Lazy Loading:

```js
// listen to an Event
$(document).bind('fbInit',function(){
    console.log('fbInit complete; FB Object is Available');
});

// FB Async
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({appId: 'app_id', 
         status: true, 
         cookie: true,
         oauth:true,
         xfbml: true});

    $(document).trigger('fbInit'); // trigger event
};
```

Comment: I love it!  The only issue is that Facebook insists that you should include your FB init code directly after the opening <body> tag, and best practice says you should load jQuery before the closing <body> tag.  Doh!  Chicken and egg.  I'm tempting to say "screw you, Facebook" and load FB after jQuery.

Comment: @EthanBrown I agree - your page probably needs jQuery more than it needs FB so that makes sense. I gave up trying to load jQuery at the end of the page years ago ;-)

Comment: add `version: 'v2.5'` in the init json other wise it will not work.. at leat did not for me. thanks for the help

Answer (score 11):

Another way to check if FB has initialized is by using the following code:

```
ns.FBInitialized = function () {
    return typeof (FB) != 'undefined' && window.fbAsyncInit.hasRun;
};
```

Thus in your page ready event you could check ns.FBInitialized and defer the event to later phase by using setTimeOut.

Comment: This is the real thing! Thanks!

Comment: This is simple one. Like it

Comment: Hey, I am from 2023, and I do wanna confirm that:


(a) you still may get "init not called with valid version" error from time to time (as for frequency -- YMMV). It happens because `fbAsyncInit` has not been run. I do not know why.

 (b) that `window.fbAsyncInit.hasRun` is a magic. it contains `true` in case all is OK and `undefined` otherwise. It does not make FB SDK inited, but at list, it will allow you to add some guards in your code

Answer (score 5):

While some of the above solutions work, I thought I'd post our eventual solution - which defines a 'ready' method that will fire as soon as FB is initialized and ready to go. It has the advantage over other solutions that it's safe to call either before or after FB is ready.

It can be used like so:

```
f52.fb.ready(function() {
    // safe to use FB here
});
```

Here's the source file (note that it's defined within a 'f52.fb' namespace).

```
if (typeof(f52) === 'undefined') { f52 = {}; }
f52.fb = (function () {

    var fbAppId = f52.inputs.base.fbAppId,
        fbApiInit = false;

    var awaitingReady = [];

    var notifyQ = function() {
        var i = 0,
            l = awaitingReady.length;
        for(i = 0; i < l; i++) {
            awaitingReady[i]();
        }
    };

    var ready = function(cb) {
        if (fbApiInit) {
            cb();
        } else {
            awaitingReady.push(cb);
        }
    };

    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
            appId: fbAppId,
            xfbml: true,
            version: 'v2.0'
        });

        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response){
            fbApiInit = true;
            notifyQ();
        });
    };

    return {
        /**
         * Fires callback when FB is initialized and ready for api calls.
         */
        'ready': ready
    };

})();
```

Answer (score 4):

### I've avoided using setTimeout by using a global function:

EDIT NOTE: I've updated the following helper scripts and created a class that easier/simpler to use; check it out here ::: https://github.com/tjmehta/fbExec.js

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        //...
    });
    window.fbApiInit = true; //init flag
    if(window.thisFunctionIsCalledAfterFbInit)
        window.thisFunctionIsCalledAfterFbInit();
};
```

fbEnsureInit will call it's callback after FB.init

```
function fbEnsureInit(callback){
  if(!window.fbApiInit) {
    window.thisFunctionIsCalledAfterFbInit = callback; //find this in index.html
  }
  else{
    callback();
  }
}
```

fbEnsureInitAndLoginStatus will call it's callback after FB.init and after FB.getLoginStatus

```
function fbEnsureInitAndLoginStatus(callback){
  runAfterFbInit(function(){
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response){
      if (response.status === 'connected') {
        // the user is logged in and has authenticated your
        // app, and response.authResponse supplies
        // the user's ID, a valid access token, a signed
        // request, and the time the access token
        // and signed request each expire
        callback();

      } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
        // the user is logged in to Facebook,
        // but has not authenticated your app

      } else {
        // the user isn't logged in to Facebook.

      }
    });
  });
}
```

### fbEnsureInit example usage:

(FB.login needs to be run after FB has been initialized)

```
fbEnsureInit(function(){
    FB.login(
       //..enter code here
    );
});
```

### fbEnsureInitAndLogin example usage:

(FB.api needs to be run after FB.init and FB user must be logged in.)

```
fbEnsureInitAndLoginStatus(function(){
    FB.api(
       //..enter code here
    );
});
```

Comment: I wrote this helper class that performs the same as above in an easier and cleaner way; check it out here:: https://github.com/tjmehta/fbExec.js

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using any setTimeout or setInterval I would stick to deferred objects (implementation by jQuery [here](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/)). It's still tricky to resolve queue in proper moment, because init don't have callbacks but combining result with  event subscription (as someone pointed before me), should do the trick and be close enough.

Pseudo-snippet would look as follows:

```
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', function(response) {
   if (response.authResponse) {
       // user has auth'd your app and is logged into Facebook
   } else {
       // user has not auth'd your app, or is not logged into Facebook
   }
   DeferredObject.resolve();
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's a simpler method, that requires neither events or timeouts. It does require jQuery, however.

Use `jQuery.holdReady()` [(docs)](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.holdready/)

So, immediately after your jQuery script, delay the ready event.

```
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $.holdReady( true ); // don't fire ready until told (ie when FB loaded)
</script>
```

Then, in your Facebook init function, release it:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId: '11111111111111',
        cookie: true,
        xfbml: false,
        version: 'v2.4'
    });

    // release the ready event to execute
    $.holdReady( false );
};
```

Then you can use the ready event as normal:

```
$(document).ready( myApp.init );
```

Answer (score 2):

You can subscribe to the event:

ie)

```
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
  FB.api('/me', function(response) {
    alert(response.name);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Small but IMPORTANT notices:

1. `FB.getLoginStatus` must be called after `FB.init`, otherwise it will not fire the event.
2. you can use `FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', callback)`, but it will not fire when user is not logged in facebook.

Here is the working example with both functions

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', function(response) {
        console.log( "FB.Event.subscribe auth.statusChange" );
        console.log( response );
    });

    FB.init({
        appId   : "YOUR APP KEY HERE",
        cookie  : true,  // enable cookies to allow the server to access
                // the session
        xfbml   : true,  // parse social plugins on this page
        version : 'v2.1', // use version 2.1
        status  : true
    });

    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response){
        console.log( "FB.getLoginStatus" );
        console.log( response );
    });

};

// Load the SDK asynchronously
(function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

Answer (score 1):

The Facebook API watches for the FB._apiKey so you can watch for this before calling your own application of the API with something like:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    //...your init object
  });
  function myUseOfFB(){
    //...your FB API calls
  };
  function FBreadyState(){
    if(FB._apiKey) return myUseOfFB();
    setTimeout(FBreadyState, 100); // adjust time as-desired
  };
  FBreadyState();
};
```

Not sure this makes a difference but in my case--because I wanted to be sure the UI was ready--I've wrapped the initialization with jQuery's document ready (last bit above):

```
  $(document).ready(FBreadyState);
```

Note too that I'm NOT using async = true to load Facebook's all.js, which in my case seems to be helping with signing into the UI and driving features more reliably.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes fbAsyncInit doesnt work. I dont know why and use this workaround then:

```
 var interval = window.setInterval(function(){
    if(typeof FB != 'undefined'){
        FB.init({
            appId      : 'your ID',
            cookie     : true,  // enable cookies to allow the server to access// the session
            xfbml      : true,  // parse social plugins on this page
            version    : 'v2.3' // use version 2.3
        });

        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
            statusChangeCallback(response);
        });
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
},100);
```