# facebook apprequests dialog error "An error occurred. Please try again later."

Tags: javascript, facebook, dialog, request

I am trying to build-in 'invite a friend' in my app. I am using FB.ui. It seems to work (I am using standard code from http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/464/.

But the iframe where you should be able to send a request to your friends just says: "An error occurred. Please try again later."

I didn't forget to use access token.

```
echo '<div id="fb-root"></div>';
echo '<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js">';
echo '  </script>';
echo '  <script>';
echo "    FB.init({appId:'215089721847404', cookie:true, status:true, xfbml:true});";

echo "    FB.ui({ method: 'apprequests', message: 'Here is a new Requests dialog...', display: 'iframe', access_token: '$token'});";
echo '  </script>';
```

Did fb stop allowing request dialogs from within apps? Or am I doing something wrong? Does someone have another solution? Please help.

Update: Maybe that is because I didn't put redirect_uri. Now I did and it doesn't give the error, but now the iframe just doesn't stop loading...
Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Request 2.0 are tricky, all parts have to be exactly as facebook wants it, or it will not work.

see http://af-design.com/blog/2011/02/17/using-facebook-requests-to-promote-a-website/ for a good example on how to do it.

Comment: for a working example see also: http://www.facebook.com/ManhattanFitness?sk=app_175200199201756

Comment: @Rufinus: -1, please provide some of the code here. Don't just link to external website. And just a side note, the way you are the code is handling the requests is **WRONG**!

Comment: @ifaour saying its wrong is also not very helpful, what is wrong ?

Comment: @Rufinus: I know it's not helpful, but you posted a link in first place. :-) anyway, handling the requests is a bit trickier...since Facebook may send you more than one id at once (you should loop through them). Check my [post](http://www.masteringapi.com/tutorials/how-to-handle-application-requests-using-the-facebook-graph-api/45/) for more info.

Comment: How could a fb user accept several requests at the same time?

Comment: @ifaour ah you mean the blogpost, this blogpost is not from me.

Comment: @Nikhil : when a user has more than one request from the same app, and accepts one of them, the application recieves all open requests for this user, so @ifaour is right about the loop, in my invite friends example i loop too.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem with several different calls the the apprequests method of the Facebook API, but intermittently.

In the end I found that the problem was being caused by calling the FB.ui function in inline javascript like you do. It would work fine sometimes, but on a slow network I always got the same error.

I fixed it by simply putting the FB.ui call within a function and using setTimeout call to trigger it after the page has completely loaded, like this

```
    function callAppReq() {
        FB.ui({ method: 'apprequests', 
                title: 'My Title', 
                message: 'Here is a new Requests dialog...'},
             function(response) {
             }
        );
    }
    var t=setTimeout("callAppReq()",3000);
```

Comment: If facebook takes more than 3 seconds to initialize, this won't work.  I'd suggest using the answer here instead: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3548493/how-to-detect-when-facebooks-fb-init-is-complete/3549043#3549043

Comment: Doesnt fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

One more possible catch is that facebook will not let you send app requests till you have configured your **app domain**..
Without mentioning app domain FB shall give you 
"An error occurred. Please try again later facebook apprequest error" consistently

**Settings >> Basic Info >> App Domains**