# My Facebook Connect .php webpage works on Chrome, Firefox, IE9 but not on IE8. It shows up as a blank white screen

Tags: internet-explorer-8, facebook

I have an APP developed that works in Chrome, Internet Explorer 9, and Mozilla but no luck in Internet Explorer 8. Even without going through Facebook, I get a blank screen in internet explorer.  What is strange is if I view the page source, I can see all of the source.  In FB it is still the same white screen.

I am using IE8.  Everything I am finding goes back to a P3P Policy.  Every site says to place a policy so that the cookies can pass and the session will run.

This is the [link](http://www.amitpatil.me/session-cookie-not-working-in-ie-p3p-site-complience/) That I found.

Yes, these have been implemented. Including the HONK hack that FB uses on their own site to bypass the IE 3rd party cookie security issue.

Yes, I have already done changed the privacy settings with no luck.

Does anyone know what's wrong with this? The code looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"

"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html id="facebook" lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>

<!-- START Init Facebook App -->

<div id="fb-root"></div>      

<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>      

<script>

FB.init({ 

  appId:'298230576859720', 

  cookie:true, 

 status:true, 

 xfbml:true,

  authResponse:true,

 oauth : true    });



 </script>

 <!-- END Init Facebook App -->



 <script type="text/javascript">



 // START Facebook JS Feed Pop Up Code 

  function FBRoutine(){ // If user isn't already authenticated or logged in get authentication



  FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {           

      if (response.authResponse) {

            // logged in and connected user, someone you know

            //alert ('authed already');

            // alert (response.status);

            // FBFeed(); // Show feed pop up

            window.location = "facebook-step-03-optin.php";

      } else {

            // no user session available, someone you dont know

            //alert ('not authed');

            //alert (response.status);

            window.location = "facebook-step-02-login.php";                

      };



   }); // End getLoginStatus

}; // End function

// END Facebook JS Feed Pop Up Code 

FBRoutine(); // Run routine to detect FB authentication prior to submitting form and after validation.      

</script>
```

Comment: Not sure if it is the cause of the problem, but your HTML is not valid. There is a `<div>` in the head section which should be in the body section, which seems to be missing completely.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your code is complete, but I'll give it a shot.
First thing, there could be a problem with IE8, try wrapping the FBRoutine(); call in document.onload ow window.onload.
Also read this, [How to detect when facebook's FB.init is complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3548493/how-to-detect-when-facebooks-fb-init-is-complete), maybe the JS SDK is not yet initialized when you are calling FB.getLoginStatus.

Please check if you have posted your complete code, good luck

Answer (score 0):

According FB documentation :

"Add an XML namespace to the  tag of your document. This is necessary for XFBML to work in earlier versions of Internet Explorer."

```
<html xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">
```