# Login by Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have realised a website that implemented a login by Facebook.
I have tested it on the browser Safari and all seems to be ok. I've just tested it on Chrome and Mozilla also, and it doesn't work. I'll paste the code, but you can find the example on http://taxigruppo.altervista.org/flogin.php .

Thank you very much.

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
            FB.init({
                appId       : "<?= YOUR_APP_ID ?>",
                status      : true,
                cookie      : true,
                xfbml       : true,
                oauth       : true
            });

            FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
                window.location.reload();
            });
        }
  <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <fb:login-button scope="<?= $permissions ?>">Login</fb:login-button>
```

If you need some other code, like PHP, tell me.

The problem is that the login button in Safari is visible al cliccable, in other browser, many time, no.

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing various values properly to Facebook. The first part of the error URL is:

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?api_key=APP_ID&app_id=APP_ID&client_id=APP_ID

which is mostly likely not what you intended. I can't really see where it's going wrong but make sure you're passing all the values correctly.

Comment: The problem isn't the login procedure but the login button. If it's visibile it works... the problem is that many time it isn't visibile and cliccable.

Answer (score 0):

One alternative can be to create the login button yourself and style it to give it the look and feel of facebook login. Make sure you obey their [policy](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/) and harm their brand value (eg. create buttons that reflects Facebook branding, not yours).

```
<span class="facebook-button">
</span>
```

And then, if you are using [jquery](http://jquery.com/) (which is very useful to use along facebook js-sdk), you can [bind](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) a [click](http://api.jquery.com/click/) event with the button.

```
$(".facebook-button").click(function{
  YOUR FUNCTION
});
```

Or else, you can have a onclick function, as well. And in the `YOUR FUNCTION`, call `FB.api()`, or similar api functions (which can be login functions too). One good example is [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/) in their docs.

Advantages:
1. Very powerful, you can do all sorts of things either server-side or client-side by this method.
2. It will be faster. You can put your jquery fancy stuff in one js file (or one aggregated file) and the browser load will be faster.

CAUTION: Sometimes you can see `FB not defined` error in console, which is beautifully dealt in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3548493/how-to-detect-when-facebooks-fb-init-is-complete).

.