# FB.getLoginStatus() called before calling FB.init() error

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm trying to get the current user login status via javascript sdk but I get the following error:

> FB.getLoginStatus() called before calling FB.init()

Here is my code:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '000000000000000000', // App ID
      status     : true, // check login status
      cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
    });

        console.log(FB.getLoginStatus); //THIS DOESN'T WORK!!

  };

  // Load the SDK Asynchronously
  (function(d){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
   }(document));
</script>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would seem that FB.init is not a synchronous call (meaning it returns before it is actually finished).  A quick google turned up this [How to detect when facebook's FB.init is complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3548493/how-to-detect-when-facebooks-fb-init-is-complete)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it by removing `#xfbml=1`
in the imported URL :

```
//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You just forgot () to call the javascript method.

```
console.log(FB.getLoginStatus);
```

is

```
console.log(FB.getLoginStatus());
```