# Facebook javascript sdk An active access token must be used to query information about the current user

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-access-token

In my code I have

```
FB.api('/me/friends', function(response) {
            if(response.data) {
                //TODO : what to do if no. of friends is more than 5000 (pagination by fb)
                friends_data=response.data;
                dijit.registry.byId("mainWidget_div").set_friends_data(friends_data);
            } else {
                alert("Error!");
            }

          });
```

And this gives an error. ***But***, if I call this function manually(on the console), there's no error

```
FB.api('/me/friends', function(response){r=response;});
//wait a while
r
```

and now `r.data` is an array of my friends.

I checked the network panel and I gather that when I call this manually, an access token automatically gets inserted in the request url and when it is getting called via the code, the access token doesn't get inserted.

The full fb sdk loading code in my application is this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      // You probably don't want to use globals, but this is just example code
      var fbAppId = "{{facebook_app_id}}";

      // This is boilerplate code that is used to initialize the Facebook
      // JS SDK.  You would normally set your App ID in this code.

      // Additional JS functions here
      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          appId      : fbAppId,        // App ID
          status     : true,           // check login status
          cookie     : true,           // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
          xfbml      : true            // parse page for xfbml or html5 social plugins like login button below
        });

        // Put additional init code here
        dojo.ready(function(){
          FB.api('/me/friends', function(response) {
            if(response.data) {
                //TODO : what to do if no. of friends is more than 5000 (pagination by fb)
                friends_data=response.data;
                dijit.registry.byId("mainWidget_div").set_friends_data(friends_data);
            } else {
                alert("Error!");
            }

          });
        });
      };
      // Load the SDK Asynchronously
      (function(d, s, id){
         var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
         if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
         js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
         js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
         fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
       }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

    </script>
```

Answer (score 4):

The [answer from Brent Baisley](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21977100/830988) and [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3549043/830988) to a different question, helped me figure out what was wrong.

You can't call FB.init() dependent methods right after FB.init() because it loads asynchronously. Even loading the data asynchronously like in dojo.ready() doesn't help. You have to wrap the code in FB.getLoginStatus().

Answer (score 2):

My guess would be that you are trying to get the list of friends before the Facebook API is fully initialized. What is the error you are seeing?

You are registering the FB.api call to be run on DOM ready (dojo.ready). That might be causing it to load out of sync, even though it's all wrapped in fbAsyncInit. The friends API call itself has no dependency on the DOM, so I wouldn't wrap it in a dojo call. You're not doing that in the console and it's working.

I'm no javascript expert. If I made a possibly incorrect guess, the reason this happens could have to do with javascript hoisting.

Comment: Thank you! You have led me to the answer, though it's not exactly the same as your guess.