# An active access token must be used to query information about the current user

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to output my Facebook feed to a div element.

Using this code:

```
<script>
      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          appId      : 'APP ID HERE',
          xfbml      : true,
          version    : 'v2.1'
        });

        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
          if (response.status === 'connected') {
            console.log('Logged in.');
          }
          else {
            console.log('initiate FB login...');
            FB.login();
          }
        });


        FB.api('/me/feed',function(response){
            var idDiv=document.getElementById('result');
            idDiv.textContent=JSON.stringify(response);
        }); 


      };

      (function(d, s, id){
         var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
         if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
         js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
         js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
         console.log(js.length);
         fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
       }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));


    </script>
<div id='result'></div>
```

I get "logged in" displayed on the console, so I know that `FB.getLoginStatus()` has returned `connected`.

The `div` element gets populated with the following error:

```
{"error":{"message":"An active access token must be used to query information
 about the current user.","type":"OAuthException","code":2500}}
```

If `FB.getLoginStatus()` returned `connected`, shouldn't there be an active access token?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You probably don't have the access token at the time the request to 'me/feed' is sent.

getLoginStatus does not only check if the user is authorized, it also refreshes the user session. that´s why it is important to do api calls after it is "connected".

Try putting the call to FB.api inside getLoginStatus.

This question is similar to the problem you're having:[Facebook javascript sdk An active access token must be used to query information about the current user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15812050/facebook-javascript-sdk-an-active-access-token-must-be-used-to-query-information?rq=1)

Comment: some more information, if you want to add it to your answer: getLoginStatus does not only check if the user is authorized, it also refreshes the user session. that´s why it is important to do api calls after it is "connected".