# Facebook Login in Selenium Tests

Tags: javascript, django, facebook, selenium, django-facebook

I'm working on a django project, using django_facebook for Facebook interaction, and Selenium for automated system testing.

In the tests, when it comes to logging to facebook from my application, I do this:

```
        self.browser.get(self.live_server_url)
        self.browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="facebook_login_js"]/input').click()

        self.browser.switch_to_window(self.browser.window_handles[1])
        self.login_to_facebook()
```

but it fails because Facebook's JS SDK hasn't finished its asynchronous initialization process. My tests used to work in the past, don't know if something changed now (like slower initialization).

I've thought of a solution like using fbAsyncInit, but that code is provided by django_facebook in a Javascript file and I don't want to touch it.

Have any idea how to wait until Facebook JS SDK is completely load so I can use the login functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally had to override Facebook initialization, so there was no problem afterwards. I simply did

```
function facebookJSLoaded(){
    FB.init({appId: facebookAppId, status: false, cookie: true, xfbml: true, oauth: 

    $('#fb-root').attr("data-sdk-loaded", 1);
};

window.fbAsyncInit = facebookJSLoaded;
F = new facebookClass(facebookAppId);
F.load();
```

(which is a solution very similar to [How to detect when facebook's FB.init is complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3548493/how-to-detect-when-facebooks-fb-init-is-complete)). In my selenium test, I wait for this attribute to appear in fb-root to click the login button.

Answer (score 1):

```
self.browser.get(self.live_server_url);
self.browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="facebook_login_js"]/input').click();

self.browser.switch_to_window(self.browser.window_handles[1]);

window.set_timeout(function(){
    self.login_to_facebook();
}, 1000)
```

The above will make it wait for one second before it calls the login. You can play with the time by changing the `1000`. `Set_timeout` takes time values in milliseconds, (hence 1000 = 1 second).

Comment: The problem is that the click does nothing as the SDK is not loaded yet. The "login_to_facebook" message is supposed to fill the login form.

Comment: @geekazoid well, put everything that you think is not working because the SDK isn't loaded yet inside of the `set_timeout()`.

Comment: Another solution I found was to "click" until two windows appears, but we know this is no good. Neither is it to wait for a second, as the load time may vary.

I was thinking of something like a change on the "fb-root" div or kinda, but cannot guess it from documentation.